# Is it possible to customize Salesforce Chat Floating Bubble in SDK both Android and iOS

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We are using Salesforce SDK both android and iOS and we wanted to brand (customize styling) the chat action floating bubble and waiting screen.[image]